# Returning an input value from a function in a class - Python

Tags: python, function, class, return

I have been trying to return a value from an input in one of my programs and cannot seem to do so when using an input, could anybody help me out? this isn't the code of my program but it's a relevant example to the issue i'm having. Thanks.

```
class one(object):

    two = ("")

    def test(self):

        two = input("Please enter a number. ")

        return self.two

        print (two)

cOne = one()
test1 = cOne.test()
```

Comment: What's your actual question? Please read [mcve].

Comment: please remove all the superfluous empty lines, and state a clear question

Comment: `two` and `self.two` are two different things...

Comment: Have you read: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 2):

you are storing the input value in `two` but returning `self.two`. Instead of that, just return `two` or assign `self.two` instead of `two`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
class One(object):
    two = ""

    def test(self):
        self.two = input("Please enter a number. ")
        print(self.two)
        return self.two

one_instance = One()
test_value = one_instance.test()
```

The print command was unreachable code (as the block is exited at the return statement), and within the function block you must use 'self.two' as opposed to 'two', which would be declaring a new variable with a different scope.

Also, extraneous brackets on third line.

Comment: please follow [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)'s naming convention (or suggest to)

Comment: `that would be creating a set containing one empty string instead of a string` not true. The parenthesis are useless indeed, but `two` is a `string`

Comment: Thank you. Corrected. Still spotting any blasphemous naming?